# Discrete Cosine Transform in image processing

Tags: image-processing

given a vector f and a scalar s
what is the difference between
DCT(f) and DCT(f+s)

and between
DCT(f) and DCT(f*s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a scalar is equivalent to adding a zero-frequency component to the signal you are about to transform, so you'll be having a larger 0th index of the DCT -- a 'peak' if you want, of value `s/k` where `k` is a constant depending a bit on your particular implementation.

Check out [this Wikibook link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signals_and_Systems/Fourier_Series#DC_Offset) as well.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a Matlab question,but a signal processing one.

In any case, if you add a scalar to a vector in Matlab, that scalar will be added to every element in the vector, as it assumes that you wanted the operation to be applied to every element.

If you multiply, it's the usual behaviour for matrix-scalar multiplication.

But again, your question is not really about the Matlab implementation of the DCT, but about the DCT itself, so maybe you should find some text detailing the properties of that specific transform.